# Bearer token in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, oauth, promise, jwt

I building web app which is using OAuth authorization. To get access to data i need ask endpoint for token and place it in Authorization header.

I have made interceptor in Angular which put right header for API call and that part works just fine.

```
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if(!(req.headers.get("Content-Type") === "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")) {

      const authReq = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorazation', 'Bearer ' + this.callToken()
          .then(resp => resp)
          .catch(err => console.log(err)))
      });
      return next.handle(authReq)
    }else {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
```

but i have this method callToken() where I used promis to call for token. 
Now this method return promise I cant put it in header in right type its always appear like [image: [Object prmice]]

```
      callToken(): Promise<any> {
    let url = 'url';
    let body = "body";
    let promise = fetch(url, {
      body: body,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      method: 'POST',
    });

    return promise
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(json => json.access_token);

  }
```

funny thing is that when I say resp => console.log(resp.acces_token) token just pretty printed.

I try use callbacks as well

```
      callForToken(): string {
    let url = 'url';
    let body = 'body';

    let option = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    };
    let token;
    this.http.post<Token>(url, body, option).subscribe(
      res => {
        token = res.access_token;
      }
    );
    return token;
  }
```

but because of async call I can't reach token data outside of method

Comment: So you're intercepting every API call to first make an API call to get the access token? That seems very inefficient. You should just get your access token at the point you "login" to your app and store that somewhere, like LocalStorage or create an AuthService, and use that in your Interceptor rather than making a call for your access token every time you make another request.

Comment: every token lives 5 minutes before being expired. That solution it's made like that for security purpose. If I will get token correctly i will make that statement to first check if token is expired and if so then call for new one

Comment: Have you tried making that intercept an `async` function then `await this.callToken()`?

Comment: when I tried to make intercept method async get an error

ERROR in src/app/auth.interceptor.ts(18,62): error TS1055: Type 'typeof Observable' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.
src/app/auth.interceptor.ts(18,62): error TS1055: Type 'typeof Observable' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.
  Types of parameters 'subscribe' and 'executor' are incompatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still try to found solution on this. 
Now I end up with

```
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!(req.headers.get('Content-Type') === 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')) {
      return Observable.fromPromise(this.handleAccess(req, next));
    }
  }


  private async handleAccess(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Promise<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = await this.callToken();
    console.log(token);

    let changeRequest;

    if (token) {
      changeRequest = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
      });
    }

    return next.handle(changeRequest).toPromise();
  }

  callToken(): Promise<Token> {
    let url = 'url';
    let body = 'body';


    return fetch(url, {
      body: body,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      method: 'POST',
    }).then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(json => json.acces_token)
      .catch(err => console.error(err));


  }
```

but still token is undefined

EDIT: actually that's work. I messed up with URL and body